# null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, null, stream-builder

Cant find the error generated from this code.
Null check operator used on a null value. The relevant error-causing was StreamBuilder<List<Message

```
class ChatList extends ConsumerWidget {
final String recieverUserId;
const ChatList({
Key? key,
required this.recieverUserId,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
return StreamBuilder<List<Message>>(stream: 
ref.read(chatControllerProvider).chatStream(recieverUserId),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Loader();
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final messageData = snapshot.data![index];
        if (messages[index]['isMe'] == true) {
          return MyMessageCard(
            message: messageData.text,
            date: messages[index]['time'].toString(),
          );
        }
        return SenderMessageCard(
          message: messageData.text,
          date: messages[index]['time'].toString(),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The message is clear "Null check operator used on a null value. The relevant error-causing was StreamBuilder<List<Message" The error is about the listView within the stream builder length.

How you've assigned it, when the data is not yet received from the server, the length property will be null so it will surely throw such an error.

so change:

```
 itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
```

to:

```
 itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
```

so your full code should be:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Message>>(
  stream: ref.read(chatControllerProvider).chatStream(recieverUserId),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Loader();
    }
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final messageData = snapshot.data![index];
          if (messages[index]['isMe'] == true) {
            return MyMessageCard(
              message: messageData.text,
              date: messages[index]['time'].toString(),
            );
          }
          return SenderMessageCard(
            message: messageData.text,
            date: messages[index]['time'].toString(),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return SizedBox();
    }
  },
)
```

You can read more about various ways of fixing the error "[Null check operator used on a null value](https://dartandflutter.com/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value/)"

Answer (score 0):

the error is related to using BANG on a value that is not yet populated.

use null checks where you use '!'.

such as:

```
snapshot.data!.length
```

to:

```
snapshot.hasdata? snapshot.data!.length: 1;
```

Comment: Tried. Does not work...

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamBuilder<List<Message>>(
  stream: ref.read(chatControllerProvider).chatStream(recieverUserId),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Loader();
    }
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final messageData = snapshot.data![index];
          if (messages[index]['isMe'] == true) {
            return MyMessageCard(
              message: messageData.text,
              date: messages[index]['time'].toString(),
            );
          }
          return SenderMessageCard(
            message: messageData.text,
            date: messages[index]['time'].toString(),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return SizedBox();
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: Thanks. It returns the SizedBox. What does it means exactly? It should not return it btw